# Jquery ui Slider not working in IE9 browser and below

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am pretty sure this question has appear many times in stackoverflow however i haven't found a concrete answer that resolves this question.

I have grabbed a basic slider from jqueryUI [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/newkidontheblock/42dCr/), i can't get this slider to work in browsers in IE 9 and 8, does anyone have the solution to this?

Initially i wanted to create this slider in angularJS however there doesn't seem to be a solution as of yet.. If any has the answer to the angular solution please can you prove me with an example..

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


   $(function() {
    $( ".slider" ).slider();
  });
```

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward i have Jquery ui and Jquery in my solution, the code has been taken from the Jquery UI website, the problem the slider doesn't work in Ie 9 and 8

Comment: Are you using jQuery 2.0? In this case IE8 support is dropped. Any errors in console?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward i have uploaded the version of Jquery i am using

Comment: Is working fine in IE9 http://jsfiddle.net/42dCr/2/, the problem is elsewhere, can you provide other infos?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward can't be, what you see in the above is all i have applied to the solution, are you sure you're not using an emulator?

Comment: No, on a real machine, jQuery works fine on IE9 any error in the console?

Comment: I have actually got working, i added a meta tag to prevent viewing in compatibility mode, which seems to have done the trick.

Comment: @NewKidOnTheBlock Please post your fix as an answer. This will help any future visitors having problems.